# conditional primary key based on value not being null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has a composite primary key:

```
   CREATE TABLE tb (
        it_service               VARCHAR2(200),
        hostname                 VARCHAR2(255),
        sw_name                  VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
        product_home             VARCHAR2(500),
        product_home_ods         VARCHAR2(500),
        instance_name            VARCHAR2(255),
        eg_status                VARCHAR2(10),
       );

ALTER TABLE tb ADD (
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb PRIMARY KEY (              hostname,
                                                instance_name,
                                                product_home,
                                                product_home_ods,  
                                                it_service,
                                                sw_name )
);
```

The problem is that when I insert into this table, the data from the `product_home` column is null for the rows where `product_home_ods` has data. The same applies `product_home_ods`, the rows where that table contain data are null for `product_home`.

Example:

```
product_home product_home_ods
java         null
python       null
null         windows
null         windows_server
```

Is it possible to create a primary key based on the condition of these columns ? I understand a primary key should not contain `null` values, but unsure about the best way to tackle this problem.

Comment: "...when I insert into this table, the data from the product_home column is null for..." -- A primary key can never be null. You are trying to add some logic to a primary key, and it's just not meant for that. You can enforce the logic you want by adding unique indexes or by using triggers. A primary key is just not the right choice here.

Comment: so there is no way to use those columns as part of the primary key unless i ignore the rows which are null, correct ?

Comment: There's no way of using a **nullable** column as part of the primary key. Period.

Comment: You can probably use a UNIQUE  constraint instead of PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And changing to this model ?
product_home will never be NULL and ods_flag will indicate if it should be interpreted a product_home or product_home_ods, something you can do in a view to get back the same data as your original table.

```
CREATE TABLE tb (
        it_service               VARCHAR2(200),
        hostname                 VARCHAR2(255),
        sw_name                  VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
        product_home             VARCHAR2(500),
        ods_flag                 NUMBER(1,0),
        instance_name            VARCHAR2(255),
        eg_status                VARCHAR2(10),
       );

ALTER TABLE tb ADD (
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb PRIMARY KEY (              hostname,
                                                instance_name,
                                                product_home,
                                                ods_flag,  
                                                it_service,
                                                sw_name )
);
```

(As long as product_home and product_home_ods of your original table are not foreign keys)

Comment: this looks nice, but i did not quite understand the idea here. Could you please be more specific ?

Comment: You avoid trying putting NULLable column in the PK and you replace the "SELECT FROM tb" by "SELECT .. FROM v_tb" where "v_tb" is a VIEW defined as  "SELECT it_service, hostname, sw_name, case ods_flag when 0 then product_home end as product_home, case ods_flag when 1 then product_home end as product_home_ods, instance_name, eg_status FROM tb"